# "Every m X n matrix over the field F is row-equivalent to a row-reduced matrix." What if a matrix has columns that are a scalar multiples of another?

Tags: linear-algebra

From Hoffman and Kunze's *Linear Algebra*: "Every m X n matrix over the field F is row-equivalent to a row-reduced matrix." I provide a picture of their proof below for reference.

An m x n matrix is row-reduced when for each row, it is either all zeroes, or its leading entry is a $1$, with only zeroes in the rest of that row, **and** the *column* that contains the $1$ has zeroes everywhere else.

So what confuses me here, is that if we supposed a matrix with arbitrary rows that has the relationship described in the title (say, column 3 entries are twice that of that row's column 2 entry), where the first row was [1 0 0] and the second [0 2 4], wouldn't the row-reduction process outlined in their proof fail to reduce this matrix in full?

To start we'd use the first row [1 0 0] to zero out the first column entries elsewhere in the matrix. And then we'd scale the second row by $\frac{1}{2}$ to get [0 1 2], and add it (scaled appropriately) to other rows until the second column was zeroed out everywhere else. In that same process, we'd simultaneously be zero-ing out the third column because of the particular relationship described for this counter-example. This would leave us with all other rows (except the first and second) as [0 0 0], and so we'd be stuck with the not-reduced row [0 1 2] with no way to zero out its third column. Does this contradict the procedure outlined in the proof below?

**Edit:** my definition of row-reduced was pulled from memory and wrong. My bad. The definition given in the book, which I misinterpreted, is that *(a) the first non-zero entry in each non-zero row of R is equal to 1;
(b) each column of R which contains the leading non-zero entry of some
row has all its other entries 0*. Thank you to those who helped.

[image: Proof of the theorem in the book]

Comment: I don't think the definition usually includes the part about the "rest of a pivot row has all $0$'s" (there are $0$'s to the left of pivot entries, but not necessarily to the right). For example, a $2 x 2$ with rows [ $1   1$] and [$0   0$] could not be reduced to that form. You can get the pivot columns to consist of a unique pivot $1$ and the rest $0$'s, but the non-pivot columns can't be forced to behave to the right of the pivots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"or its leading entry is a 1, with only zeroes in the rest of that row" is wrong. Do they really give that definition of reduced matrix??

Comment: Oh, my word, that was my incorrect mental shortcut. You're completely right. They say that the *column* that the 1's are in must have zeroes everywhere else, and I think I blurred that with "row". So the counter-example I constructed isn't counter. Thank you.